# Serilog to AzureTableStorage ConnectionString

Tags: serilog, .net-7.0

I have a WebApi developed with Net core 7 and deployed on Azure.
I use AzureTableStorage Serilog sink and this is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      // Verbose < Debug < Information < Warning < Error < Critical
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "AzureTableStorage",
        "Args": {
          "storageTableName": "log",
          "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
          "keyGenerator": "Shared.Middlewares.MyKeyGenerator, Shared"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  }
}
```

How can I avoid writing the connectionString in plain text to this file?

I have already defined the same connectionString in an AppConfiguration. Is it possible to read it from here?